# performing SQL SELECT query inside the loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a table `leave_muster` inside which I have to update all the records of the previous month on every start of the new month.

**My Code**

```
public function sync()
    {
        $pre_month = (int)date('m') - 1;

        $data = $this->Leave_muster_model->get_by_month($pre_month);

        $updated_data = [];

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            // Fetch each employee details to perform some check
            // Then update the array and 

            $updated_data[$key] = [
                'emp_id'                   => $value->emp_id,
                'accumulated_leaves'       => 0.0,
                'total_accumulated_leaves' => 0.0,
                'leave_taken'              => 0.0,
                'salary_deducted_days'     => 0.0,
                'leave_balance'            => 0.0,
                'month'                    => date('m'),
                'year'                     => date('Y'),
                'created_date'             => date('Y-m-d')
            ];
        }

    }
}
```

In the above code, I have to fetch the employee details before updating the leaves to perform some checks, So I have two ways

1. Fetch the employee details inside the loop before any update to
   perform checks.
2. Fetch all the employee details outside the loop into
   an array then get the employee by employee id the perform checks

I want to know which would be a better approach as I know that in any given point of time in the future there won't be any millions of employees in the table.

**Lang: PHP 

Framework: Codeigniter**

Comment: second one i would prefer, you can play with array the way you like...database read-write-etc is a time consuming operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, I treat calls to my database as expensive; I work to reduce the number of database calls my scripts perform. Thus, I would probably load all employees, then run thru the loop.

This assumes that there will not be a a lot of employees. In which case you'll run into memory issues.

Comment: If I assume that I will not have more than 2k records in the array, will that create a memory issue?

Comment: No, that should be fine. But try it, I don't know how big your rows are, nor what you're planning to do with them.